# `SumConvergence` gives different results for two equivalent series

Tags: bugs, summation

**Bug persisting through v12.0.0.0 and resolved in v12.1.0.0**

Consider these two sequences:

```
a = 2^n/(n! Gamma[(1 - n)/2]^2);
b = Simplify[a /. n -> 2 m]
```

It turns out that sequence `a` is just sequence `b` interspliced with the zero sequence: sequence `a` is zero for odd `n`, as can be verified with `Simplify[a /. n -> 2 m + 1, {m \[Element] Integers, m >= 0}]`.

Since these two sequences have the same nonzero entries, their sum convergence should be identical. But `SumConvergence[a, n]` returns `True` while `SumConvergence[b, m]` returns `False`. Why is this?

v12.0.0.0

Comment: `SumConvergence[a, n]` does not return true in Mathematica v12.1.1. It just returns the input back. `SumConvergence[b, m]` still returns False.

Comment: For my Mathematica in Ver12.1.0, the result is the same as flinty's.

Comment: @flinty Dangit, I guess I was just one sub-version away from working!

Comment: @tparker well it doesn't work - it should really tell me True or False - not stay unevaluated.

Comment: @flinty Ideally, yes. But I'll give an unevaluated but technically correct answer a pass (like we do with integrals) - although not a wrong answer.